# Why this program gives a Segmentation Fault while calling a function?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This is a part of my program while I run this program I get a segmentation fault. I've narrowed it down to the line:

> checkBase(ptr1, ptr2)

i'm passing both of these as pointers. and they are declare as char* and its a runtime error not compile time.
 file contains

> < a href = "http://www.google.com"> www.spam.google.com < /a >

in this case ptr1 = www.google.com and ptr2 = spam.google.com

```
while(inf){

    count++;
    getline(inf, line);
    //cout << "*******" << count << "*******" << endl <<line << endl;
    p = new char[line.length()+1];
    strcpy(p, line.c_str());
    if(strstr(p, "href")){

        ptr = strstr(p, "href");
        while(ptr[0]!='\0'){
            ptr += 1;
            if(ptr[0] == 'w' && ptr[1] == 'w' && ptr[2] == 'w'){
                cout << ptr << endl;            
                ptr = strtok(ptr, "\"");
                cout << "add1   " << ptr << endl;
                add1 = ptr;
                ptr1 = ptr;
                ptr = strtok(NULL, "> ");
                add2 = ptr;
                ptr2 = ptr;
                cout << "ptr1: " << ptr1 << endl << "ptr2: " <<ptr2 << endl;
                if(add1 == add2)
                    cout << "There is an exact match at line: " << count << endl << line << endl;
                else{
                    cout << "in else" << endl;
                    checkBase(ptr1, ptr2); //THIS GIVES A SEGMENTATION FAULT
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void checkBase(char *add1, char *add2){
    cout << "here" << endl;
    char *base1[1000000], *base2[1000000];
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    base1[count1] = strtok(add1, ".");
    while(base1[count1] != NULL){
        count1++;
        base1[count1] = strtok(NULL, ".");
        cout << base1[count1] << endl;
    }
    base2[count2] = strtok(add2, ".");
    while(base2[count2] != NULL){
        count2++;
        base2[count2] = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }
    cout << base2[count2-1] << endl;
    if(((strcmp(base1[count1-1],base2[count2-1])) != 0) && (strcmp(base1[count1-2], base2[count2-2]) != 0)){
        //if((strcmp(base1[count1-1], base2[count2-1]) != 0)){
        cout << "Bases do not match: " << endl
             << base1[count1-2] << "." << base1[count1-1] << " and "
             << base2[count2-2] << "." << base2[count2-1] << endl;
        //}
    }
    else{
        cout << "Bases match: " << endl
             << base1[count1-2] << "." << base1[count1-1] << " and "
             << base2[count2-2] << "." << base2[count2-1] << endl;          
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this is giving a segmenation fault.

Comment: Run it under the watchful eye of a debugger and I bet you'll quickly find out. And the single line of code you've identified that is tripping your fault? yeah, thats the code that *isn't here.*

Comment: Please add the code for your `checkBase` function. A lot of segfaults are caused by using pointers that aren't correctly initialized to a valid piece of memory. I can only speculate that is the issue until I see your code for your `checkBase` function.

Comment: Add the portion of the code in which you actually declare your variables

Comment: Also check that ptr1 and ptr2 aren't null...

Answer (score 3):

```
char *base1[1000000], *base2[1000000];
```

No doubt this is causing stack overflow. The stack is limited in size, and creating arrays more than a few kb in size is a bad idea. Try allocating them on the heap, for example `vector<char *> base1(1000000)`

You should also calculate the exact size required and allocate that much, or push_back on the vector.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems, beyond the stack overflow already mentioned by @Neil Kirkwell

1. Those shouldn't be while loops solely conditioned on base1[count1] != NULL; you should also make sure count1 is less than the number of elements in the array.
2. If either count2 or count1 is 0 or 1 you will be trying to reference index of -1 and -2... not so good.
3. use strrchr to search backwards and make your life easier
4. It's wasteful to build those arrays entirely, since you only seem to care about the last two tokens, you only need two pointers in each.

i.e.

```
char *one_a = NULL, *one_b = NULL, *two_a=NULL, *two_b = NULL;
char *temp = strtok(add1, ".");
while (temp) {
    one_b = one_a;
    one_a = temp
    temp = strtok(NULL, ".");
}
char *temp = strtok(add2, ".");
while (temp) {
    two_b = two_a;
    two_a = temp
    temp = strtok(NULL, ".");
}
//now just compare one_a with two_a and one_b with two_b and you're done.
```